# bash: stop a for loop if the internal command exits with non-zero code

Tags: bash

I have this code:

```
for x in 1 2 3;
do
  ./test.sh $x
done
```

test.sh looks like this

```
echo "$1"
if [ "$1" = "2" ]
then
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi
```

how do I get it to output only

```
1
2
```

Instead of

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`break` if the test.sh fails:

```
for x in 1 2 3;
do
  ./test.sh $x || break
done
```

Comment: thanks.  but to add another layer of complexity to the same question, how do I do it with a nested loop, such as [this](https://pastebin.com/erTDyaib)

Comment: To ask a new question, create a new question. You can link to the old one if you feel their relation is important.